# PulseAudio stuttering and choppy sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm fearly new to Ubuntu. I installed PulseAudio Equalizer and i spend nearly 5 hours fixing stuffs from pulseaudio (from tutorials and other stuffs). The sound is still choppy when forwarding, stuttering when surfing the net, it has delay.

I can't stand to this sound I'm audiophile, and this is driving me crazy. If someone can tell me other equalizer or some miracle setting i will be very pleased.

Comment: Was it choppy, stuttering, and delayed on browsing the Internet before you had installed the `pulseaudio-equalizer`? What is you hardware?

Comment: Nah, it's becoming that when i enable qpaeq (the equalizer). I have Lenovo G50-70 laptop with Dolby capable speakers. I tried multiple ways to fix pulseaudio (from arch linux site, they have good suport for pulseaudio as far as i can tell).

Comment: You hardware may be insufficient to run the pulseaudio equalizer in addition to additional software (brower, video decoding, games, ...?).

Comment: It's not my hardware. There is million posts about how bad pulseaudio equalizer is. On my main PC with new hardware it's the same On my other laptops it's the same.

Comment: I had the same problem and posted an Issue about that. Please like it so they see it:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/1087

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this helps, but I have the same problem. Does not 'solve' the problem, but if I turn off my wifi and turn it back on, the stutter sound has gone away.  Of course, every time I reboot/boot, I have to wait for the wifi to connect, then turn it off/on to get rid of the 'stutter'  or unwelcome 'pop' sounds.

Comment: worked for me. thank you very much